# How to find extra unversioned files after 'svn update --accept postpone'

Tags: svn, merge

If I use `svn update --accept postpone` in conflicted checkout, then I've got the conflicted file (`filname`) and 3 extra unversioned file ([see doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve.pending)) - 
`filename.mine`, `filename.rOLDREV`, `filename.rNEWREV`.

**How to find this extra files from script, in conflicted checkout browsing?** These files marked as `unversioned` after update was finish, without any special properties. Yes, `svn resolve filename` should to find it, but I want to detect it to show to the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
svn info conflicted_file_name
```

For example for conflicted `t.txt`

```
scn info t.txt
```

output

```
Path: t.txt
Name: t.txt
Working Copy Root Path: D:\test\users\u2_conflict\repo4conflict
URL: file:///D:/test/repo4conflict/text/t.txt
Relative URL: ^/text/t.txt
Repository Root: file:///D:/test/repo4conflict
Repository UUID: ca805198-e653-c549-a95b-e74c0053aff8
Revision: 3
Node Kind: file
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: Y.N
Last Changed Rev: 3
Last Changed Date: 2015-08-10 17:12:53 +0300
Checksum: d9e2a264aec5085a8d670266a9064f6c0e57a4c6
Conflict Previous Base File: t.txt.r1
Conflict Previous Working File: t.txt.mine
Conflict Current Base File: t.txt.r3
Source  left: (file) ^/text/t.txt@1
Source right: (file) ^/text/t.txt@3
```

Use the `svn info conflicted_file_name --xml` to parse the results.

Answer (score -1):

> How to find this extra files from script?

As it written in doc: every file with 'C' status will add three files with the same name and changed extensions

```
C    sandwich.txt
Updated to revision 2.
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 1
$ ls -1
sandwich.txt
sandwich.txt.mine
sandwich.txt.r1
sandwich.txt.r2
```

Comment: This is output of update. I need to find these files on conflict resolving flow.

Comment: I do not find the `ls -1` option. `hg` - it's a mercurial command, svn 1.8 has not `-l` option for `resolve`